# Showing the polarization of (complex) quadratic form is sesquilinear.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, quadratic-forms, riesz-representation-theorem, sesquilinear-forms

Let $q: V\times V \to \mathbb{C}$ on a complex vector space $V$ be a quadratic form. Define $\tilde q$ by the polarization identity:

$$
\begin{equation}
\tilde q(\phi,\psi)  = \frac{1}{4} [q(\phi + \psi) -q(\phi - \psi) + iq(\phi + i\psi) - iq(\phi - i\psi)]  
\end{equation}
$$

***My question is how can I show that $\tilde q$ is sesquilinear?***

My plan is to show that (1) $\tilde q$ is skew-symmetric, and (2) linear in the second argument. However, to show (2), I'm not exactly sure how to do so given that $q$ is defined in complex space. I found a hint that tells me to show that

> a. $\tilde q(\phi, 2\psi) = 2\tilde q(\phi, \psi)$ 
> b. $\tilde q(\phi, \psi + \psi') = \tilde q(\phi, \psi) + \tilde q(\phi, \psi')$
> c. $\tilde q(\phi, \pm i\psi ) = \pm i\tilde q(\phi, \psi)$
> d. $\tilde q(\phi, \alpha\psi ) = \alpha\tilde q(\phi, \psi )$ for all dyadic rationals in $\mathbb C$.

It makes sense to me that we need to take the complex part into account for $c$ and $d$. However, I have no idea what $d$ means. Also for $a$, is the number 2 just some random real integer?

---

PS: Here's the definition I want to use for (complex) quadratic form:

> 1. $q(\lambda x) = |\lambda|^2q(x)\quad \forall \lambda\in\mathbb C, x\in V$
> 2. $q(\phi+\psi) + q(\phi-\psi) = 2q(\psi)+2q(\phi)$

From 2, we could rewrite the polarization identity as

$$
\tilde q(\phi,\psi) = \frac{1}{2}[q(\phi+i\psi)-q(\phi)-q(\psi)] - \frac{i}{2}[q(\phi+i\psi)-q(\phi)-q(i\psi)]
$$

But I'm unsure if that's helpful for showing $\tilde q$ is sesquilinear.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is $V$ assumed to be finite-dimensional over $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: @Ewan Delanoy I think here $V$ should refer to the Hilbert Space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the given hints are quite helpful. Nevertheless a complete proof is somewhat lengthy. Here we show part (a).

We consider $\tilde q: V\times V\to \mathbb{C}$ which fulfills the *polarisation identity*:
\begin{align*}
\tilde q(\phi,\psi)  = \frac{1}{4} [q(\phi + \psi) -q(\phi - \psi) + iq(\phi + i\psi) - iq(\phi - i\psi)]  \tag{1}
\end{align*}

We obtain for $\phi,\psi,\xi\in V$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\tilde{q}}&\color{blue}{(\phi,\psi)+\tilde{q}(\phi,\xi)}\tag{2.1}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(q(\phi+\psi)-q(\phi-\psi)+iq(\phi+i\psi)-iq(\phi-\psi)\right.\\
&\quad+\left.q(\phi+\xi)-q(\phi-\xi)+iq(\phi+i\xi)-iq(\phi-\xi)\right)\tag{2.2}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(q\left(\left(\phi+\frac{\psi+\xi}{2}\right)+\frac{\psi-\xi}{2}\right)
+q\left(\left(\phi+\frac{\psi+\xi}{2}\right)-\frac{\psi-\xi}{2}\right)\right.\\
&\quad-q\left(\left(\phi-\frac{\psi+\xi}{2}\right)-\frac{\psi-\xi}{2}\right)
-q\left(\left(\phi-\frac{\psi+\xi}{2}\right)+\frac{\psi-\xi}{2}\right)\\
&\quad+iq\left(\left(\phi+i\frac{\psi+\xi}{2}\right)+i\frac{\psi-\xi}{2}\right)
+iq\left(\left(\phi+i\frac{\psi+\xi}{2}\right)-i\frac{\psi-\xi}{2}\right)\\
&\quad\left.-iq\left(\left(\phi-i\frac{\psi+\xi}{2}\right)-i\frac{\psi-\xi}{2}\right)
-iq\left(\left(\phi-i\frac{\psi+\xi}{2}\right)+i\frac{\psi-\xi}{2}\right)\right)\tag{2.3}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(q\left(\phi+\frac{\psi+\xi}{2}\right)+q\left(\frac{\psi-\xi}{2}\right)
-q\left(\phi-\frac{\psi+\xi}{2}\right)-q\left(\frac{\psi-\xi}{2}\right)
\right.\\
&\quad\left.+iq\left(\phi-i\frac{\psi+\xi}{2}\right)+iq\left(\frac{\psi-\xi}{2}\right)
-iq\left(\phi+i\frac{\psi+\xi}{2}\right)-iq\left(\frac{\psi-\xi}{2}\right)\right)\tag{2.4}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=2\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\frac{\psi+\xi}{2}\right)}\tag{2.5}
\end{align*}

> Putting $\xi=0$ in (1) we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\tilde{q}(\phi,0)}=\frac{1}{4} [q(\phi) -q(\phi) + iq(\phi) - iq(\phi)] \color{blue}{=0}\tag{2.6}
> \end{align*}
> Combining (2.1), (2.5) and (3) we finally obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\tilde{q}(\phi,\psi)=2\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\frac{\psi}{2}\right)}\tag{2.7}
> \end{align*}
> and the hint (a) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2.2) we use the *polarisation identity* (1) for both terms $\tilde{q}(\phi,\psi)$ and $\tilde{q}(\phi,\xi)$.
- In (2.3) we split the terms conveniently as preparation for the next step.
- In (2.4) we apply the *parallelogram identity*
  \begin{align*}
  q\left(\phi+\psi\right)+q\left(\phi-\psi\right)=2\left(q\left(\phi\right)+q\left(\psi\right)\right)
  \end{align*}
- In (2.5) we cancel terms and apply (1) again.

**Note:** This derivation follows closely section 1.2 of *[Linear Operator in Hilbert Spaces](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-6027-1)* by Joachim Weidmann. The other parts can also be derived from this section.

---

---

*Add-on [2022-04-17]:*

With respect to comments to this post here is some additional information. In order to show sesquilinearity of $\tilde{q}:V\times V\to \mathbb{C}$ we have to show for all $\phi,\psi,\xi\in V$ and for all $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\tilde{q}\left(a\phi+b\psi\xi\right)}&\color{blue}{=a\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\xi\right)+b\tilde{q}\left(\psi,\xi\right)}\tag{*}\\
\color{blue}{\tilde{q}\left(\phi,a\psi+b\xi\right)}&\color{blue}{=a^{*}\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\psi\right)+b^{*}\tilde{q}\left(\psi,\xi\right)}\tag{**}\\
\end{align*}
which is *linearity* in the first component and *[antilinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilinear_map)* in the second component. We now list the steps which can be used to show (*) and (**) together with some details.

> **additivity second component**
>
> In order to show *antilinearity* in the second component we show at first *additivity*
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\psi+\xi\right)=\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\psi\right)+\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\xi\right)}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

We obtain from (2.1) and (2.5)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\tilde{q}(\phi,\psi)+\tilde{q}(\phi,\xi)}&=2\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\frac{\psi+\xi}{2}\right)\tag{$\to 2.5$}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\tilde{q}(\phi,\psi+\xi)}\tag{$\to 2.7$}
\end{align*}
and additivity (3) follows.

> **additivity first component**
>
> We want to show
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\tilde{q}\left(\phi+\psi,\xi\right)=\tilde{q}\left(\psi,\xi\right)+\tilde{q}\left(\psi,\xi\right)}\tag{4.1}
> \end{align*}
> and do so by establishing at first
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\psi\right)^{*}=\tilde{q}\left(\psi,\phi\right)}\tag{4.2}
> \end{align*}

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\tilde{q}(\phi,\psi)^{*}}
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(q\left(\phi+\psi\right)-q\left(\phi-\psi\right)
+i q\left(\phi+i\psi\right)-i q\left(\phi-i \psi\right)\right)^{*}\tag{$\to (1)$}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(q\left(\phi+\psi\right)-q\left(\phi-\psi\right)\right)\\
&\qquad+\frac{1}{4}\left(-i q\left((i)\left(\psi-i\phi\right)\right)+i q\left((-i)\left(\psi+i \phi\right)\right)\right)\tag{$\to\rm{def}$}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(q\left(\psi+\phi\right)-q\left(\psi-\phi\right)
+i q\left(\psi+i \phi\right)-i q\left(\psi-i\phi\right)\right)\\
&\,\,=\color{blue}{\tilde{q}(\psi,\phi)}
\end{align*}
and (4.2) follows. We now obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\tilde{q}\left(\phi+\psi,\xi\right)}&=\tilde{q}\left(\xi,\phi+\psi\right)^{*}\tag{$\to (4.2)$}\\
&=\left(\tilde{q}\left(\xi,\phi\right)+\tilde{q}\left(\xi,\psi\right)\right)^{*}\tag{$\to (3)$}\\
&=\tilde{q}\left(\xi,\phi\right)^{*}+\tilde{q}\left(\xi,\psi\right)^{*}\tag{$\to \rm{def}$}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\xi\right)+\tilde{q}\left(\psi,\xi\right)}\tag{$\to (4.2)$}\\
\end{align*}
and the claim (4.1), additivity in the second component follows.

> **conjugate homogeneity second component**
>
> We want to show for all $\phi,\psi \in V$ and for all $a\in \mathbb{C}$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\tilde{q}\left(\phi,a\psi\right)=a^{*}\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\psi\right)}\tag{5.1}
> \end{align*}
> In order to show (5.1) for arbitray $a\in\mathbb{C}$ we proceed in some steps starting with *[dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational)*. We can show
> \begin{align*}
> \tilde{q}\left(\phi,\frac{m}{2^n}\psi\right)&=\frac{m}{2^n}\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\psi\right)\qquad\qquad m,n\in\mathbb{N_{0}}\tag{5.2}\\
> \tilde{q}\left(\phi,a\psi\right)&=a\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\psi\right)\qquad\qquad\quad\  a\in\mathbb{R_{0}^{+}}\tag{5.3}\\
> \tilde{q}\left(\phi,a\psi\right)&=a\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\psi\right)\qquad\qquad\quad\  a\in\mathbb{R}\tag{5.4}\\
> \tilde{q}\left(\phi,a\psi\right)&=a^{*}\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\psi\right)\qquad\qquad\quad a\in\mathbb{C}\tag{5.5}\\
> \end{align*}

- (5.2): Based upon (2.7) we can show the validity for dyadic rationals by induction.
- (5.3): Since the set of dyadic rational numbers is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we can use a continuity argument to show the validity of (5.1) for $a\geq 0$. In order to do so we recall that for a norm $p:V\to\mathbb{R}_0^{+}$ we have due to the triangle inequality
  \begin{align*}
   |p(\phi)-p(\psi)|\leq p\left(\phi\pm\psi\right)
   \end{align*}
  It follows for all $\phi,\psi\in V$ and for all $a, a_k\geq 0$
  \begin{align*}
  |p\left(\phi\pm a_k\psi\right)-p\left(\phi\pm a\psi\right)|
  &\leq p\left(a_k\psi-a\psi\right)\leq \left|a_k-a\right|p(\psi)\\
  |p\left(\phi\pm i a_k\psi\right)-p\left(\phi\pm i a\psi\right)|
  &\leq p\left(i a_k\psi-i a\psi\right)\leq \left|a_k-a\right|p(\psi)\\
  \end{align*}
  which can be used in conjunction with the *polarisation identity* (1) to show the claim. We use thereby a sequence $(a_k)_{k\geq 0}$ of non-negative dyadic rationals converging to $a\geq 0$.
- (5.4): Here we can use (1) to show $\tilde{q}\left(\phi,-\psi\right)=-\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\psi\right)$ from which (5.4) follows.
- (5.5): Here we can use (1) to show $\tilde{q}\left(\phi,i\psi\right)=-i\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\psi\right)$ from which (5.5) follows.

and the claim (5.1), conjugate homogeneity in the second component follows.

> **homogeneity first component**
>
> We want to show for all $\phi,\psi \in V$ and for all $a\in \mathbb{C}$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\tilde{q}\left(a\phi,\psi\right)=a\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\psi\right)}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\tilde{q}\left(a\phi,\psi\right)}&=\tilde{q}\left(\psi,a\phi\right)^{*}\tag{$\to(4.2)$}\\
&=\left(a^{*}\tilde{q}\left(\psi,\phi\right)\right)^{*}\tag{$\to(5.1)$}\\
&=a\tilde{q}\left(\psi,\phi\right)^{*}\tag{$\to \rm{def}$}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=a\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\psi\right)}\tag{$\to (4.2)$}\\
\end{align*}
and the claim (6), homogeneity in the first component follows.

**Conclusion:** We have shown $\tilde{q}:V\times V \to \mathbb{C}$ fulfills additivity in both components, homogeneity in the first component and conjugate homogeneity in the second component, so that (*) and (**) follows. This shows that mappings $\tilde{q}$ for which the *polarisation identity* is valid are sesquilinear forms.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! The reference is also really helpful:)

Comment: Very nice answer, +1. Just an additional small question : I clearly see how to show that $\tilde q(\phi, \alpha\psi ) = \alpha\tilde q(\phi, \psi )$ for all dyadic rationals $\alpha$ as the OP says, and we know the dyadic rationals are dense. But it is unclear to me how to extend this further to all $\alpha\in{\mathbb R}$. My guess is that you have to pass through some continuity-showing inequality of the form $|\tilde q(\phi, \alpha\psi )- \tilde q(\phi, \beta\psi )| \leq C|\alpha-\beta|$, right ? How does one show such an inequality ?

Comment: @Ewan Delanoy I'm reading the reference on page 11. It seems that they showed the dyadic rationals from induction, and $\alpha$ could be any real and complex number. I was still a bit confused why do we need to introduce the idea of dyadic rationals here?

Comment: @IGY:  It is the relation $\tilde{q}(\phi,\psi)=2\tilde{q}\left(\phi,\frac{\psi}{2}\right)$ which admits a generalisation to dyadic rationals, and which makes this kind of generalisation quite a natural one. Then we can continue with a continuity argument to go from dyadic rationals to reals.

Comment: @epi163sqrt Thanks, that helps!

Comment: I also got a question for the first argument: to show that $\tilde q$ is skew-symmetric (the first condition), would that be equivalent to show $\tilde q(ax,y) = a\tilde q (x,y)$ for all $a \in\mathbb C$? Thanks :)

Comment: No problem, thanks for the nice answer :)

Comment: The hint says I could try to show that $̃ (\phi,\psi)=̃ (\psi,\phi)^*$ for the first argument (skew-symmetric), but I'm a bit confused if that results linarity.

Comment: @IGY: Once again many thanks for granting the bounty. :-) I've added some details also addressing skew-symmetry which might be helpful.

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: I've revised my answer. The continuity argument is based upon consideration of norms of real fields. This is sufficient, since in this step we want to show the conjugate homogeneity for non-negative reals only.

Comment: Here are my questions about your new addendum : what is the relation between $q$ (the quadratic form) and $p$ (the norm) ?  In the first equation in your explanation on (5.3), you have a $q_0(\psi)$ in $|p(\phi)-q_0(\psi)|\leq p\left(\phi\pm\psi\right)$, what is this $q_0$ ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: $q_0$ was a typo, thanks. I'm sorry, but at the time I can't provide a correct reasoning to close this gap.